# Clojure unit testing issue

Tags: clojure

I've currently got a function in my main file which squares every number in the list, now that works perfectly with no errors but my unit tests keeps on throwing errors and I cant seem to figure out why.

```
 (ns squareone.core-test
 (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]
        [squareone.core :refer :all]))

(deftest Squaring
  (testing "Squaring test"
    (is (= [1 16] (square [1 4])))))
  That is everything in my test file
```

And this is what is in my main file minus the actual squaring function

```
(ns squareone.core)
(:require '[clojure.string :as string])
(require '['clojure.string :as 'str])
```

And I get this error

```
Syntax error (ClassCastException) compiling at 
(C:\Users\public\squareone\src\squareone\core.clj:3:1).
class clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast to class clojure.lang.Symbol 
(clojure.lang.PersistentList and clojure.lang.Symbol are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

Very unsure on how to proceed, any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Please check syntax for `ns` and for `require`. Parens and quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax error is on line 3 which is:

```
(require '['clojure.string :as 'str])
```

and we can confirm in a REPL that is indeed illegal:

```
user=> (require '['clojure.string :as 'str])
Execution error (ClassCastException) at user/eval1 (REPL:1).
class clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast to class clojure.lang.Named (clojure.lang.PersistentList and clojure.lang.Named are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

You also have a problem on line 3, but it doesn't cause a syntax or runtime error:

```
(:require '[clojure.string :as string])
```

This attempts to look up the keyword `:require` in the literal vector `[clojure.string :as string]` -- the leading quote (`'`) prevents evaluation so that is a symbol (`clojure.string`) followed by a keyword (`:as`) followed by another symbol (`string`). Looking up a keyword `:require` in a vector is going to return `nil`.

I expect what you were trying to do was this:

```
(ns squareone.core
  (:require [clojure.string :as string]))
```

Note where the parentheses are: the `:require` form is part of the `ns` declaration.

At this point, you should be able to delete line 3 and move on to testing.

Why is line 3 illegal though?

The quote (`'`) is shorthand for wrapping a form in `(quote ..)` and that in turn prevents evaluation. You have three quotes in line 3, so it expands to this:

```
(require (quote [(quote clojure.string) :as (quote str)]))
```

The outer quote prevents evaluation, so the argument that is passed to the `require` function is: `[(quote clojure.string) :as (quote str)]` which is a vector containing a list with two symbols (`quote` and `clojure.string`), a keyword (`:as`), and another list of two symbols. But `require` expects just a symbol in those slots like this:

```
(require '[clojure.string :as str])
```

and that's the error you are getting: expected `clojure.lang.Symbol` but got `clojure.lang.PersistentList`.